# pfsense - Not getting the LAN connection

Tags: networking, home-networking, pfsense

Pfsense newbie here.

Below is my setup.
Router > PF Sense on a HP desktop with 3 ports> TpLink Switch > Laptop
(see picture1 below)

PfSense is getting WAN IP and the internet connection. See picture 2 and 3 below

But still, the laptop connecting to the switch is not getting the LAN connection.
Its not getting any IP when connecting via the LAN cable below.
I have verified the switch works well when I take out pfsense from the equation.
Looks like It is not getting the default gateway assigned? How do I assign that?

Can somebody help?
What am I missing?

**Picture 1**
[image]
**Picture 2**
[image]
**Picture 3**
[image]

**Picture 4**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your WAN and LAN are on the same subnet.  That defeats the purpose of a firewall/router, and no need to have pfsense in use at all.

Your WAN and LAN **MUST** be on separate networks.

pfsense can see the 'internet' though you seem to also be doing this as a lab test, with you WAN connected to your internal firewalled network.  Try setting LAN to 192.168.2.254/24.  Also ensure dhcp is enabled in pfsense.  The 169 address indicated unable to connect to dhcp.